# How do I configure AzureVM to allow me to make API calls?

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-vm

Novice here, apologies if this is a rookie question. I have set up a test Azure VM (using the $200 free credit) and am trying to make API calls to two different websites using Python. Both calls work fine on my local desktop, but when I run them on the Azure VM, one API fails (response code 403) while the other succeeds (response code 200). Neither API request takes long when run on my desktop - each takes about 2 seconds to complete.

*two API calls with results when run on VM*
[image: two API calls with results when run on VM]

In the Azure VM Networking screen, I have added an Inbound rule to allow any HTTPS.

*VM>>Networking>>Inbound Port Rule*
[image: VM>>Networking>>Inbound Port Rule]

My goal is to be able to run my Python code on a task scheduler on the Azure VM and write the results to SQL Server on the VM. But I can't get both API calls to be successful. Thanks for any guidance on this.

Comment: 403 is a permission problem, it's possible calls from your local desktop are allowed due to their origin IP, or perhaps you're using a different client and it has the appropriate cookies while the application on your VM does not - that's just two reasons why a 403 might happen, there's many more, it's impossible to say without knowing more. It's not a firewall issue on the client on the VM, because you get the 403 from the server.

Comment: Great, thank you for the response. That's helpful in pointing me in the right direction.